# Ordered containers with O(Log2(n)) operations

Tags: time-complexity, data-structures

Could You please recommend ordered data structures with the complexity of reading/writing/deleting not slower than O(Log2(n)), traversing O(n*Log2(n))? SkipList, Red-Black Tree, what else?

Comment: AVL trees support searches, insertions, and deletions in time $O(\log n)$, and (as for any balanced BST) a standard symmetric visit gives you all elements in non-decreasing order in time $O(n)$, which is actually slightly stronger: $O(1)$ amortized time per element. If you implement it properly, you can also ensure that the time between two consecutive elements is $O(1)$ in the worst case.

Comment: Also, the standard implementation of skip-lists achieves the bounds you asked for only if you consider expected times (not in the worst-case).

Comment: B trees and B+ trees too obey the aforementioned bounds.

Comment: Any kind of balanced search trees. (Tranversal in $O(n)$, I never heard of traversal in $O(n\log n)$.)

Comment: if you are okay with skiplists (which have an expected logarithmic runtime for operations) then perhaps splay trees as well as the other suggestions in the comments.